# Converting an array into list format

Tags: php, html, xml

How can I modify this xml data to appear in a list format?

```
foreach ($dataArray['simpleforecast']['forecastday'] as $arr) {
    $html .= "<td align='center'>" . $arr['date']['weekday'] . "<br />";
    $html .= "<img src='http://icons-pe.wxug.com/i/c/a/" . $arr['icon'] . ".gif' border=0 /><br />";
    $html .= "<font color='red'>" . $arr['high'][$tempScale] . $tempUnit . " </font>";
    $html .= "<font color='blue'>" . $arr['low'][$tempScale] . $tempUnit . "</font>";
    $html .= "</td>";
}
```

Comment: also the data shows me a 6 day forecast including current day... how can i modify it to not show the current day. thanks

Comment: to array me the external data in a list format instead of horizontally, but M_rk helped me out with that by just changing the tags to <li>.

Comment: now i need to find out how to make it so that it dosnt show me the current day information, instead to skip it and only show the rest... for example if today is monday. i only want it to show me tuesday wednesday thursday etc. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm just assuming you mean this, because you're not really clear at describing what you wanted.

```
$html = "<ul>";
foreach ($dataArray['simpleforecast']['forecastday'] as $arr) {
    $html .= "<li>" . $arr['date']['weekday'] . "<br />";
    $html .= "<img src='http://icons-pe.wxug.com/i/c/a/" . $arr['icon'] . ".gif' border=0 /><br />";
    $html .= "<font color='red'>" . $arr['high'][$tempScale] . $tempUnit . " </font>";
    $html .= "<font color='blue'>" . $arr['low'][$tempScale] . $tempUnit . "</font>";
    $html .= "</li>";
}
$html .= "</ul>";
```

To skip the current day you could use the following pseudo code on the third line

```
if(today) continue;
```

But since I do not now ow to check whether it is to day, I left this open for you to figure out.

Comment: thanks for that M_rk i completely overlooked that it was in table format... it now shows in a list thanks. However, i cant make it NOT show todays information... i tried the if statement you mentioned but it dosnt seem to work.

Comment: any idea why? or maybe it needs to use 'date' somehow aswel?

Comment: the weather data is parsed from an external source. and $arr['date'] gets the current day information and ['weekday'] shows the weeks forecast.... i just want it to not display the current day or hide it.

Comment: or if that is not possible can i make it so that is replaces the current day with the word "Today" ?

Comment: As I said the line `if(today) continue;` was just pseudo-code and was meant to illustrate the idea.

Comment: You could perhaps check `$arr['date']['weekday']` against some value of [`date()`](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). 
Please look through the documentation I linked to to find out how it works. You would probably need either `date("N")` or `date("l")`.